# org.jvnet.winp.WinpException: Failed to read environment variable table when killing a job in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, ant

The machine details are its a Windows 7. I have had issues with the directories etc previously. I had to change the windows password yesterday and after that I have started getting the above error when ever I kill a task through Jenkins. 
The Jenkins service is started with my user id and password.

An ant build file is invoked when running this job.

The full trace is as below -

The error that I get is ERROR: Build step failed with exception

```
org.jvnet.winp.WinpException: Failed to read environment variable table error=299 at .\envvar-cmdline.cpp:201
at org.jvnet.winp.Native.getCmdLineAndEnvVars(Native Method)
at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.parseCmdLineAndEnvVars(WinProcess.java:126)
at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.getCommandLine(WinProcess.java:102)
at org.jvnet.winp.WinProcess.killRecursively(WinProcess.java:66)
at hudson.util.ProcessTree$Windows$1.killRecursively(ProcessTree.java:425)
at hudson.util.ProcessTree.killAll(ProcessTree.java:141)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.destroy(Proc.java:379)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:352)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:389)
at hudson.tasks.Ant.perform(Ant.java:217)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408
```

Comment: Have you restarted the Jenkins service? That will be necessary for the service to use the new credentials.

Comment: Hi Chad, yes done that. I fixed the problem though still not sure why. I changed the default ant to point to ant 1.9.4 in the configure job. Thats fixed the above. I guess the default ant with Jenkins is not being run in admin mode so when it tries to kill the job it can't get a handle.